# Adding link for logged in user?

Tags: plugins, php

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { '<a class="btn" href="/author/<?php global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo $current_user->display_name;
?>">Channel</a>'; } else { echo 'Welcome, visitor!'; } ?>
```

Anyone knows how to fix this function I wanna put in header?

Comment: Put this  in header.php in your theme file

Comment: I did link for logged in users doesnt work. It is just empty.

Comment: PHP doesn't work inside of a `'` quoted string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    echo '<a class="btn" href="/author/' . 
        $current_user->display_name . 
        '">Channel</a>'; 
} else { 
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!'; 
} 
?>
```

Note that `get_currentuserinfo()` is **deprecated** in favour of [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/).